# Windows 10 VM not loading

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

So I am trying to run a Windows 10 Virtual Machine (using VMware), it works when I'm using the latest version of VMware form Linux (DeepinOS latest version on kernel 5.10) but not when I'm on Windows 10 (build 21343.1000). In the VM, Windows Setup loads but just befor I get the UI, it just shuts down. Any help?
The old question is at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67079322/windows-10-vm-not-loading

EDIT: Fixed grammar and some other stuff

Comment: Logs in https://gofile.io/d/dxTmqf

Comment: From the other question, you said VMware does not work with a Windows 10 Host and Windows 10 Guest. I have VMware Workstation V16 newest on Windows 10 20H2 newest.  Are you trying to use a Windows Insider Host?  (21343).  Also you need a different install file for Windows host than for Linux hosts.

Comment: I did some testing for you. VMware Workstation Pro V16.1.1 build-17801498 .  I have this running on Windows 10 20H2 19042.928 and it runs several guests Windows and Linux. I installed VMware Workstation on Windows Insider 21354.1 and it installed properly and runs well. I did have to select the box during install to allow coexistence with Hyper-V.  I copied over a Windows 7 Guest and that opened up and ran well.  So with reference to the above, what is not running for you?

Comment: Thanks, what is not running is the Virtual Machine, after testing: every operating system I have downloaded works on VMware for Linux, but only Linux works on VMware for Windows (I am using Windows 10 Pro build 21343.1000 and VMware Workstation 16.1.2 build-17966106)

Comment: Also an older (but same) question is in https://superuser.com/questions/1657629/windows-is-not-running-in-a-vmware-vitual-machine