# Windows is not running in a VMware Vitual Machine

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

I am trying to use Windows 10 (and also the leaked Windows 11) in a Virtual Machine but if I try to run the Virtual Machine it just stops working (it shows me "Press any key to bot from CD/DVD" like normal, then the Windows logo and the Virtual Machine crashes before I even get to the setup)

Comment: It should work fine (I have Windows 10 in a VM before.  Did you download the ISO and install Windows 10 inthe machine? or just try to run the ISO file as a machine (that will not work).

Comment: Also the same question is in https://superuser.com/questions/1641564/windows-10-vm-not-loading

Comment: And FYI I just created the VM like normal